# How to detect sequence of 01 of odd length by regex

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match by regex strings of 01 which have odd length.
Example: `"0","001","111","11111" etc.`

The idea is the odd length sequences are 0 or 1 followed by pairs of 0 or 1. But my regex seems not working.
I made this:

```
String regex = "[0-1]{1}[[0-1]{2}]{0,}";
    String txt = "01";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);

        System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Comment: The string "seems not working" is not a built-in error message in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
String regex = "[01]([01][01])*";
"00011".matches(regex) => true
"0001".matches(regex) => false
```

Comment: @anthony good point but I believe there is an assumption that the data will only contain 0 and 1.  Otherwise it should be \b[01](?:[01]{2})*\b

Comment: @jsobo Yes. But I don't know for sure what OP wants to get. Yes, may be your variant is better suits his need.

Comment: @zoom tried that one worked as I wanted, why regex needed different group brackets?

Comment: @RobertKilar because `[abc]` - means any symbol from a or b or c. `(abc)` - means exactly "abc" - string of length 3.